# T SQL - Count People with Visits in 3 consecutive months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

With the following data:

```
Declare @t Table 
(
Name        Varchar(1),
VisitDate   Date
)

Insert Into @t select 'A','2017-01-05'
Insert Into @t select 'A','2017-03-05'
Insert Into @t select 'A','2017-04-05'
Insert Into @t select 'A','2017-05-05'
Insert Into @t select 'A','2017-08-05'
Insert Into @t select 'B','2017-03-05'
Insert Into @t select 'C','2017-01-05'
Insert Into @t select 'C','2017-02-05'
Insert Into @t select 'C','2017-04-05'
Insert Into @t select 'D','2017-01-05'
Insert Into @t select 'D','2017-02-05'
Insert Into @t select 'D','2017-03-05'
Insert Into @t select 'D','2017-06-05'
Insert Into @t select 'B','2018-01-05'
Insert Into @t select 'B','2018-02-05'
Insert Into @t select 'B','2018-03-05'
Insert Into @t select 'E','2018-01-05'
Insert Into @t select 'E','2018-02-05'
Insert Into @t select 'E','2018-03-05'
Insert Into @t select 'E','2018-06-05'
```

I need to write a query that will return the Year & Names that have VisitDates in any three consecutive months in any year.

Based on the data, I expect to see:

```
2017 A
2017 D
2018 B
2018 E
```

To be honest, I don't know where to start with this using SQL.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the counter reset after december?

Comment: @Salman: Yes. It does. Thanks.

Comment: Does the sequence `1st Feb, 31st Mar, 30th Apr` count?  You're literally just looking for 3 sequential calendar months, even if two events are 1 day away from being two months apart?

Comment: @MatBalie: Yes. Even if they are one day from being two months apart - and even if they are a day apart [28th Feb., 1st Mar.]. Just so long as they are in three consecutive calendar months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just join the two following months to the data and see where it goes:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, m1.VisitDate), m1.Name
FROM @t m1
  JOIN @t m2 on m2.Name = m1.Name AND DATEPART(month, m2.VisitDate) = DATEPART(month, m1.VisitDate) + 1
  JOIN @t m3 on m3.Name = m1.Name AND DATEPART(month, m3.VisitDate) = DATEPART(month, m1.VisitDate) + 2
```

since it was asked in the comment, how to solve this problem with a year overlap, this should work:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, m1.VisitDate), m1.Name
FROM @t m1
  JOIN @t m2 on m2.Name = m1.Name AND EOMONTH(m1.VisitDate,1) = EOMONTH(m2.VisitDate)
  JOIN @t m3 on m3.Name = m1.Name AND EOMONTH(m1.VisitDate,2) = EOMONTH(m3.VisitDate)
```

doc on EOMONTH: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

edit: my answer is just a quick hack and highly inperformant and has errors when there are multiple instances per month.
I suggest using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669713/4903754

Comment: What about when there's Dec 2017, Jan 2018, Feb, 2018?

Comment: Original question was: I need to write a query that will return the Year & Names that have VisitDates in any three consecutive months in any year.

therefore no need to check dates in the next year

Comment: @Isitar is correct. The VisitDates have to be in 3 consecutive months AND in the same calendar year.

Comment: @Isitar: I used your second suggestion - but both work. N.B. I fiddled with my data and found that a Year-Name combination would appear twice if I have a Name in 4 consecutive months - 3 times if I have a name in 5 consecutive months ... etc. No reflection on your solution, however, because my test data does not display this possibility. Thanks!!

Comment: Goes bonkers when there are multiple events in a single month *(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08cdce94ce6993759c127dd00f9a8970)*, and the use of functions in the join predicates prevents use of indexes.  Joins + no use of indexes + massive duplication of results = seriously inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the joins, or parsing the whole data set multiple times, by using the same method as used in `gaps-and-islands`.

http://rextester.com/SYHJ40676

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    Name,
    YEAR(VisitDate)         AS VisitYear,
    MONTH(VisitDate)        AS VisitMonth,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY Name, YEAR(VisitDate)
                ORDER BY MONTH(VisitDate)
           )
                            AS MonthSequenceID
  FROM
    @t
  GROUP BY
    Name,
    YEAR(VisitDate),
    MONTH(VisitDate)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  Name,
  VisitYear
FROM
  sequenced
GROUP BY
  Name,
  VisitYear,
  VisitMonth - MonthSequenceID
HAVING
  COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

### wrote my code as per the syntax of postgres SQL 9.5.0

first I have created the flag for consecutive months and by using that flag retrieved the required `data.lag(),lead()`

We need to compare the dates weather they are in consecutive or not for that I'm using `lag(),lead()` functions.

```
with temp as (

select name,visitdate, 

coalesce(lag(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate),lead(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate))check1,

coalesce(lead(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate),lag(visitdate) over (partition by name order by visitdate)) check2

from TT 

order by 1
),

 t2 as (

select name,

case

when
 (DATE_PART('year', visitdate::date) - DATE_PART('year', check1::date)) * 12 +
              (DATE_PART('month', visitdate::date) - DATE_PART('month', check1::date))=1 

or 

(DATE_PART('year', check2::date) - DATE_PART('year', visitdate::date)) * 12 +
              (DATE_PART('month', check2::date) - DATE_PART('month', visitdate::date))=1 

then 1 else 0

 end as flag

 from temp)

select name ,count(1) from t2 where flag=1  group by name having count(1)>=3
```

[image]